# Using multiple computers (per dev) and Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

everyone.

This is my very first question here, so I apologize in advance for any violations of protocol.

We have recently moved to VSO/TFS for source control of our code, and all of us have multiple computers we work on, the usual desktop/laptop combination.

I would like to know what the proper and best practice is for switching computers mid-work. We have been using the Shelve option, but it seems cumbersome and not exactly meant to be used in this way, when all that needs to happen is the switching of computers.

I have personally tried mapping my workspaces to 3 of the major cloud-storage solutions, Dropbox, Box, and OneDrive for Business. All 3 have problems with "perpetual" syncing and slow syncing. What I mean is that they cannot seem to handle the constant file changing that is happening when Visual Studio is happening, and these services don't provide good options for syncing only certain folders.

We really want to keep the workspace mapping in its default location and use the VSO/TFS system to move the code around the machines, but obviously without checking in incomplete work.

Is Shelving the correct practice for this scenario?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, shelving was intended to handle this type of scenario.

Another option is to use a Git-backed Team Project; you can then work in a local branch and publish that local branch if you need to swap PCs.

Ideally, however, regardless of the type of version control you're using, you should make small, frequent commits to source control as "checkpoints".